# Ubuntu Static Network Issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
$ ip address flush eth0 #i flushed out the old ip
$ route add default gw 192.xx.xx.xx eth0 #adding g.way
```

i get this error

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable.
```

I use Ubuntu on VM box over wifii. Network settings - Briged adapter.

Comment: Is that address supposed to be reachable after you flush the addresses?

Comment: Well, you deleted your IP from the interface and then try to add a gateway to a network you're no longer connected to because you deleted the IP from the interface. Of course that doesn't work, you first have to add a static address to that interface. See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en The fact that it's a VM doesn't matter, for Ubuntu inside the VM it shows a normal interface, the bridge configuration is done on the host.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Exactly yes.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding this is expected behaviour.

```
$ ip address flush eth0 #i flushed out the old ip
```

This command removes every IP address assigned to the adapter eth0. So this adapter does not have an IP assigned currently. Now you try to set a default route. But this cannot work since the adapter does not know how to reach the next hop.

Try setting an IP to the interface first, make sure the IP is in a subnet that can reach your default GW:

```
$ ip addr add IP/NETMASK dev DEVICE
```

You should now be able to reach the gateway, but not beyond it. Then you should be able to set a route to reach devices beyond the default gateway.

```
$ route add default gw 192.xx.xx.xx eth0
```